# Changing a php var form payment handling

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, paypal

Context: I'm creating a WordPress website where users can upload their own posts via frontend by paying a posting fee.

Here is how it works: the user uploads their post data inside a form created with the plugin WP User Frontend Pro; once they click on the "submit" button, they are redirected to the payment page and, once the payment is complete, the system handles the PayPal IPN confirmation and publishes the post.

I have this code snippet created by WP User Frontend Pro that handles the PayPal gateway:

```
<?php

public function prepare_to_send( $data ) {
        $user_id          = $data['user_info']['id'];
        $listener_url     = add_query_arg( 'action', 'wpuf_paypal_success', home_url( '' ) );
        //$listener_url     = 'http://a53d2f68b609.ngrok.io/?action=wpuf_paypal_success';
        //$listener_url     = 'https://wpuf.sharedwithexpose.com/?action=wpuf_paypal_success';
        $redirect_page_id = wpuf_get_option( 'payment_success', 'wpuf_payment' );

        if ( $redirect_page_id ) {
            $return_url = add_query_arg( 'action', 'wpuf_paypal_success', untrailingslashit( get_permalink( $redirect_page_id ) ) );
        } else {
            $return_url = add_query_arg( 'action', 'wpuf_paypal_success', untrailingslashit( get_permalink( wpuf_get_option( 'subscription_page', 'wpuf_payment' ) ) ) );
        }

        $billing_amount = empty( $data['price'] ) ? 0 : $data['price'];

        if ( isset( $_POST['coupon_id'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['coupon_id'] ) ) {
            $billing_amount = WPUF_Coupons::init()->discount( $billing_amount, $_POST['coupon_id'], $data['item_number'] );

            $coupon_id = $_POST['coupon_id'];
        } else {
            $coupon_id = '';
        }

        $data['subtotal'] = $billing_amount;
        $billing_amount   = apply_filters( 'wpuf_payment_amount', $data['subtotal'] );
        $data['tax']      = $billing_amount - $data['subtotal'];

        if ( $billing_amount == 0 ) {
            wpuf_get_user( $user_id )->subscription()->add_pack( $data['item_number'], $profile_id = null, false, 'free' );
            wp_redirect( $return_url );
            exit();
        }

        if ( $data['type'] == 'pack' && $data['custom']['recurring_pay'] == 'yes' ) {
            if ( $data['custom']['cycle_period'] == 'day' ) {
                $period = 'D';
            } elseif ( $data['custom']['cycle_period'] == 'week' ) {
                $period = 'W';
            } elseif ( $data['custom']['cycle_period'] == 'month' ) {
                $period = 'M';
            } elseif ( $data['custom']['cycle_period'] == 'year' ) {
                $period = 'Y';
            }

            if ( $data['custom']['trial_duration_type'] == 'day' ) {
                $trial_period = 'D';
            } elseif ( $data['custom']['trial_duration_type'] == 'week' ) {
                $trial_period = 'W';
            } elseif ( $data['custom']['trial_duration_type'] == 'month' ) {
                $trial_period = 'M';
            } elseif ( $data['custom']['trial_duration_type'] == 'year' ) {
                $trial_period = 'Y';
            }

            $paypal_args = [
                'cmd'           => '_xclick-subscriptions',
                'business'      => wpuf_get_option( 'paypal_email', 'wpuf_payment' ),
                'a3'            => $billing_amount,
                'mc_amount3'    => $billing_amount,
                'p3'            => ! empty( $data['custom']['billing_cycle_number'] ) ? $data['custom']['billing_cycle_number'] : '0',
                't3'            => $period,
                'item_name'     => $data['custom']['post_title'],
                'custom'        => json_encode(
                    [
                        'billing_amount' => $billing_amount,
                        'type'           => $data['type'],
                        'user_id'        => $user_id,
                        'coupon_id'      => $coupon_id,
                        'subtotal'       => $data['subtotal'],
                        'tax'            => $data['tax'],
                    ]
                ),
                'shipping'      => 0,
                'no_note'       => 1,
                'currency_code' => $data['currency'],
                'item_number'   => $data['item_number'],
                'rm'            => 2,
                'return'        => $return_url,
                'cancel_return' => $return_url,
                'notify_url'    => $listener_url,
                'src'           => 1,
                'sra'           => 1,
                'srt'           => intval( $data['custom']['billing_limit'] ),
                'recurring'     => 1,
            ];

            if ( $data['custom']['trial_status'] == 'yes' ) {
                $paypal_args['p1'] = $data['custom']['trial_duration'];
                $paypal_args['t1'] = $trial_period;
                $paypal_args['a1'] = 0;
            }
        } else {
            $paypal_args = [
                'cmd'           => '_xclick',
                'business'      => wpuf_get_option( 'paypal_email', 'wpuf_payment' ),
                'amount'        => $billing_amount,
                'item_name'     => isset( $data['custom']['post_title'] ) ? $data['custom']['post_title'] : $data['item_name'],
                'no_shipping'   => '1',
                'shipping'      => '0',
                'no_note'       => '1',
                'currency_code' => $data['currency'],
                'item_number'   => $data['item_number'],
                'charset'       => 'UTF-8',
                'rm'            => '2',
                'custom'        => json_encode(
                    [
                        'type'      => $data['type'],
                        'user_id'   => $user_id,
                        'coupon_id' => $coupon_id,
                        'subtotal'  => $data['subtotal'],
                        'tax'       => $data['tax'],
                    ]
                ),
                'return'        => $return_url,
                'notify_url'    => $listener_url,
            ];
        }
        $this->set_mode();
        
?>
```

What I'm focusing on here is the $billing_amount var.
At the moment, this var value is declared via a setting inside the plugin and it is a fixed number value: what I can do is simply change the "posting fee" by changing the value inside the plugin's form settings.

I would like, if possible, to change the value based on some radio/checkbox input fields that the user selects inside the posting form that comes before the payment page (as described before). I already know how to change an input value via JS, but I have no idea on how I could pass this JS value to the $billing_amount var.

Comment: So you want to add more fields to your form and resulting $data, and then use that information to calculate the $billing_amount. We can't very well suggest anything with specificity without knowing what you've added and seeing the resulting $data

Comment: @PrestonPHX actually, I didn't mean to calculate the $billing_amount using $data. I was looking (if possible) for a more simple approach, since I can calculate the $billing_amount via JavaScript. The problem here is that I don't know how to pass that JS amount to the $billing_amount php var

Comment: At which point are you calculating the $billing_amount via JavaScript? Is that & other information then being sent to your PHP...? That would be where to get the data from, but you aren't showing these parts of your flow.